# Латинская приставка IN - это русская НЕ?

Tags: этимология

Вопрос языковеду:
Русское **НЕСЕРЬЕЗНО** имеет родственника в латинском **IN-CURIOSUS**  в значении "беспечный, беззаботный, небрежный" (переход русской С в лат. С).

В обоих словах - имею место приставки.
Несомненно, кто-то  у кого-то  заимствовал: мы у латинян, они они у нас.

Или это всего лишь калька?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то приставка in- в латыни обозначает " движение вовнутрь или на поверхность", а отрицательная она в английском в латинских глаголах-заимствованиях.

А то, что у Вас написано, скорее всего - это курьёзный. Это слово  было известно в России со времен Петра I, заимствовано из французского языка, в который оно пришло из латыни. Курьез – смешной, необычный случай.
Латинское – curiosus (заботливый, тщательный). С приставкой ин получается выход из состояния тщательного.

http://enc-dic.com/semenov/Kurez-1024.html

Фасмер утверждает, что заимствовано через нем. kurios "странный, интересный" из лат. curiōsus "любознательный" или франц. curieuх – то же;

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!
Ваш ответ интересен. Надо подумать.

Comment: Подумал над Вашим ответом. Вы были правы.

Я нашел следующее:
Лат. IN употребляется в приставочных значениях О, БЕЗ, ИЗ, В, ВО, ПОД, ПЕРЕ, ПО и, вероятно в других (захотите - приведу примеры).

Но более всего IN существует в значении отрицания НЕ или БЕЗ.

Посмотрите сами ЧТО творится в латинском языке:

IN-VALIDES - бессильный.
IN-CONSTANS - непостоянный.
IN-FINIBILIS - нескончаемый. 
INCOCTUS - невареный.
INNUBIS - безоблачный;
IN-VIDENS - невидящий, незрячий.
IN-FIDELIS - неверующий, неверный.
IN-VINIUS - непьющий.
IN-VOLUNTAS - нежелание,
INVOLUNTARIE - невольно и мн.др.

Comment: Кажется, таких слов очень много, сотни.
Предостаточно их и в "молодых" западноевропейских языках. 

В отношении приведенного мной лат. IN-CURIOSUS достаточно посмотреть на замененную лат. С на русскую С и прочитать "по-русски": СУРЬОСУС. А поскольку IN, как я Вам только что показал, очень часто используется в латинском в значении НЕ, то налицо следующий перевод: 

IN-CURIOSUS = НЕ-СУРЬОСУС, т.е. НЕСЕРЬЕЗНО.

Не подумайте, что я сошел сума. Уже найдено слишком много подобных примеров, чтобы сомневаться в наличии такой "странной" связи между русским и латинским языком. Это мое мнение.

Comment: Лингвистика так не считает.